# Is there any eclipse plugin that can generate code notes or structure?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, eclipse-plugin, ide

When i read source code ,there are a lot of operations like switching between classes ,this is so frequent.  Call hierarchy does help, but it needs switch ,and can not edit, i need an overview notes to mark class hierarchy or specifically methods, when i click my notes ,it will navigate to a class file or method ,is there any plugin that matches my needs.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing sounds just like the javadocs feature within eclipse. These javadocs are text files that are made to annotate and document each class, method, and subclass. Furthermore, javadocs provide the same navigation capabilities you mentioned. I attached a video showing how to generate them.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5yIoA6JdS18

Comment: java doc generates a fixed structure, as i know ,it can not link to class files directly, or make you organize your layouts .I mean like a side bar or inner window in eclipse ,which allows me to tag or set a link chain myself , maybe it is not related  classes, for example  layout  class A method a() ->Class B method b()  ，there is no any extension  or calling relation  when i click classA ,navigate me to ClassA methodA , i dont have to shortcut type in ClassA for search .when i work on ClassB  ,i need to switch back to ClassA ,i just need to click ClassA super link.